# Cannot upgrade to Vuetify 2^ - Not properly bootstrapped

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm getting a slew of errors, all of which point me to answers stating that Vuetify hasn't been bootstrapped properly. I've followed the guide, I've tried every option, I cannot get it to work.

Most recently using the **Full Install** flavor.

**main.js**

```
// vuetify
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

import App from './App.vue'

import store from '@/store' 
import router from '@/router'

// import font-awesome icons
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faTimes, faClock, faRocket, faCircle, faBell, faCreditCard, faGifts, faGift, faUserNinja,  } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faTwitter, faGithub, faTwitch, faVuejs } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

library.add(faVuejs, faGithub, faTwitter, faTwitch, faTimes, faClock, faRocket, faCircle, faBell, faCreditCard, faGift, faGifts, faUserNinja);
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

// use global snackbars
import VueSnackbar from 'vue-snack' 
import 'vue-snack/dist/vue-snack.min.css'

Vue.use(VueSnackbar, { position: 'bottom-right', time: 3000 })

// use vue-resource
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);

// use axios
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(axios, VueAxios)

// vue icons
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

// vue-notifications
import Notifications from 'vue-notification'
Vue.use(Notifications)

// create global event bus
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue(); 

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

// define opts, use vuetify
const opts = {}
Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify: new Vuetify(opts),
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

---

Using the **vue-cli plugin** flavor

**plugins/vuetify.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  },
});
```

**main.js**

```
import App from './App.vue'

import store from '@/store' 
import router from '@/router'

// import font-awesome icons
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faTimes, faClock, faRocket, faCircle, faBell, faCreditCard, faGifts, faGift, faUserNinja,  } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faTwitter, faGithub, faTwitch, faVuejs } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

library.add(faVuejs, faGithub, faTwitter, faTwitch, faTimes, faClock, faRocket, faCircle, faBell, faCreditCard, faGift, faGifts, faUserNinja);
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

// use global snackbars
import VueSnackbar from 'vue-snack' 
import 'vue-snack/dist/vue-snack.min.css'

Vue.use(VueSnackbar, { position: 'bottom-right', time: 3000 })

// use vue-resource
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);

// use axios
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(axios, VueAxios)

// vue icons
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

// vue-notifications
import Notifications from 'vue-notification'
Vue.use(Notifications)

// create global event bus
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue(); 

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Console output:**
[image]

I'm not sure what could be wrong here. I have verified `"vuetify": "^2.0.18",` is installed. Is there a possible missing dependency or something I missed in the upgrade guide?

Comment: What Vue version are you on? `Vue.observable` was added in 2.6. By careful to ensure you check the Vue version and not the Vue CLI version.

Comment: That was all it was of course! Yarn wasn't properly updating Vue (Missing packages error) so I was <2.6 which was incompatible. Thank you so much.